# Navbar doesn't open when url is multiple layers deep

Tags: javascript, navbar

I have a working button which opens a navbar. It works when the url is example.com or example.com/blog BUT if it is example.com/blog/blog-piece (mutliple extensions to the url) then the button doesn't work. The console reports no errors. It is like the click event is just not captured. I am confused by this and am  wondering if javascript is doing something funny with event bubbling or something else. Thanks

button works with this url
[working url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbBN0.png)
button doesn't work with this url
[url doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJIkT.png)
[url doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clq0V.png)

```
const globalWrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.global-wrapper');
const sidebarBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__btn');
const sidebarWrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-wrapper');
const sidebarOverlay = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-overlay');

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

   if (e.target.closest('.sidebar__btn')) {
      openSidebar();
   }
   if (e.target.closest('.close')) {
      openSidebar();
   }
   if (e.target.closest('.sidebar-overlay__visible')) {
      openSidebar();
   }
   if (e.target.closest('.sidebar-link')) {
      openSidebar();
   }

});

function openSidebar() {
   for (let i = 0; i < sidebarBtn.length; i++) {
      sidebarWrapper[i].classList.toggle('sidebar-transform');
      sidebarOverlay[i].classList.toggle('sidebar-overlay__visible');
      globalWrapper[i].classList.toggle('wrapper-transform');
   }
}
```

Helper classes

```
.sidebar-transform
{
    transform: translateX(0px);

    @include MQ(s)
    {
        transform: translateX(0vw);
    }
}

.wrapper-transform
{
    transform: translateX(-414px);
}

.sidebar-overlay__visible
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    opacity: .5;
    background-color: $brand-1;
}
```

Comment: On any of the pages that it does not work, is there any other javascript that is working?

Comment: No I do not believe so @NathanFries. The JS file is very small, no third part libraries. Only possibility is the cookie policy code (but unlikely to involved in this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the JS file is being loaded?

Comment: Hey - I have had a long play with it now and that was indeed the problem. On that paritcular page the js file was not being loaded. I didn't even consider this since the previous page and all other pages the file was loading ( I don't know how I missed this console error in Firefox). So I had no reason to believe it wasn't being loaded. Anyway Jekyll was making a new page, but those new pages did not have a layout attached or in my case the js file link. So no javascript. I have since rearranged the permalink structuring and got it working. Sorry to waste your time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, Ill make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the URLs shown in the pictures, it looks like different methods are being used to serve different pages (some static, some not?). Since there is nothing in the JS file that would function or not depending on the URL, I believe the JS file is likely not being loaded on the static pages